# Roots of height 1 are necessarily simple.

Tags: linear-algebra, reflection, root-systems

Suppose $\Phi$ is a root system, $\Pi \subset \Phi$ is a fundamental system (let $\Pi = \{r_1,...,r_l\}$). Now any root $r \in \Phi$ is a linear combination of the elements of $\Pi$ with all the coefficients either non-negative or non-positive:
$$r = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{l} \lambda_i r_i.$$
Define $h : \Phi \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ to be
$$h(r) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{l} \lambda_i.$$
It is well-known that $h(r)=1$ if and only if $r$ is a fundamental root. Okay, one direction is obvious: if $r$ is fundamental, then $h(r) = 1$. But why does it work in the opposite direction? I.e. I do not understand, why if $h(r)=1$, then $r$ is necessarily simple? Why does the situation like $r = \frac12 r_1 + \frac12 r_2$ cannot happen?

Answer (score 1):

Because for any root $r \in \Phi$ can be written as linear combination of the elements of $\Pi$ with all the **integer** coefficients either non-negative or non-positive.

Comment: Yes, but to prove this, we actually use the fact $h(r) = 1$ iff $r$ is primitive.

Comment: Is it simply a solving equation $ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{l} \lambda_i=1$ over non-negative integers?

Comment: But we don't know yet that all $\lambda_i$ must be integers. After we have shown that $h(r)$ implies the fact that $r$ is simple, we can prove that all the coefficients are integral, but we need something different as an argument to show the implication.